# how to differentiate two array value from array_walk result

Tags: php, arrays, function, oop, mysqli

i have a problem in fetching value from database using array_walk function.
i want to pass a array to function and want to retrieve result in different variables and need to sum of both.
ex.

```
  class algo{

function Gender_count($value){

    $db=new DB_Connect();

    /*add code to get gender and age group value dynamic */

    $query="select count(gender) from tc_fbusermaster where gender="."'".$value."'"."and age between 20 and 21";
    $r=$db->execute($query);
    $count=mysqli_fetch_row($r);
    print_r($count);
    echo $count[0];
}

    $d=new algo();
$a=array('male','female');
array_walk($a,array($d,'Gender_count'));
```

Thanks yeah.but i think you could not understand my question.let me explained. i want to count like this... and that all should be dynamic from database.and if suppose in future i want to add one more parameter like income that code can be allow me do like that.

-------15-20  20-40     40+(age group)

Male    10     35       5

Female  23     34       48

SUM     33     69       53

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Your Gender_count method executes the query wrong. $db->execute is for executing prepared statements.
This should work.

```
function Gender_count($value){
    $db=new DB_Connect();
    $value = $db->real_escape_string(stripslashes($value))  //sanitising input.
    /*add code to get gender and age group value dynamic */
    $query="select count(gender) as gender_count from tc_fbusermaster where gender="."'".$value."'"."and age between 20 and 21";
    $res=$db->query($query);
    //Check if the query exectued successfully.
    if(!$res){
        die(mysqli_error($db));
    }
    $count=$res->fetch_assoc();
    print_r($count);
}
```

Comment: no its gives me a different different array.but i want one single array.